# Converting something like 0x0EB8 from a string to an int32 type?

Tags: c#, int32

I need to take a vendor ID from a user in the form of an int32, and they usually look something like this.
0x0EB8
I can write this as code

```
    int32 vid = 0x0EB8;
```

That works just fine. But I need to get it from the user in the form of a string. And when I call System.Convert.ToInt32("0x0EB8") I get a Type Conversion Exception.

here is some of my test code that gives me the exception.

```
        Int32 blah;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Vendor ID");
        string blahString = Console.ReadLine();
        blah = Convert.ToInt32(blahString);
```

Anyone know a good way to do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass in the radix as second parameter.

```
int blah = Convert.ToInt32(blahString, 16);
```

Comment: See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a look at MSDN's [How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx) to learn how to convert hexadecimal to numeric types.

A sample from that article:

*Note: you need to drop the '0x' from your original hexadecimal string*

```
string hexString = "0EB8";
int num = Int32.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: Checked that out and it helped alot. I was looking around the MSDN for thew convert class but that was of no help the hex page helped.